# How does Ethgasstation algorithm work?

Tags: ethgasstation

I would like to understand how the Ethgasstation algorithm works. I did not find its explanation of reasoning.
I found the explanation of another algorithm that looks like Ethgasstation but not exactly that of Ethgasstation.
Thank you.

Comment: Which part exactly? It has lots of information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably quite straightforward:

- Check the previous X blocks
- See what gas prices have been used in them
- See how long the transactions have taken with certain gas prices
- Possibly extrapolate results into the near future
- Display the results in the TX calculator to estimate near-future gas prices and how long transactions take with them

Comment: Anything is possible, but I doubt it uses any sophisticated methods such as deep learning. Simple extrapolation is probably enough.

Comment: I don't think they just make use of a linear trend for example. Probably the more recent tx will be weighted more than the other ones. Thus giving a result that is more accurate. Either way great job +1